# I have these to variables on a html 5 canvas. I want the alert you lose when myGamePiece collides with the myWall or the myWall2?

Tags: javascript, html

```
function startGame() {
    myGamePiece = new component(30, 30, "red", 10, 120);
    myGameArea.start();

    myWall = new defense(30, 150, "black", 90, 120)
    myGameArea.start();

    myWall2 = new defense(30, 150, "black", 180, 0)
    myGameArea.start();
}

            var myGameArea = {
       canvas : document.createElement("canvas"),
     start : function() {
          this.canvas.width = 338;
         this.canvas.height = 270;
         this.context = this.canvas.getContext("2d");
         document.body.insertBefore(this.canvas, 
    document.body.childNodes[0]);
          this.interval = setInterval(updateGameArea, 20);
     },
     clear : function() {
          this.context.clearRect(0, 0, this.canvas.width, 
   this.canvas.height);
     }
  }
    function defense(width, height, color, x, y) {
     this.width = width;
      this.height = height;
      this.x = x;
      this.y = y;
      this.update = function() {
          ctx = myGameArea.context;
           ctx.fillStyle = color;
            ctx.fillRect(this.x, this.y, this.width, this.height);
      }

         this.newPos = function(){
          this.x;
            this.y;
      }

   }

     function component(width, height, color, x, y) {
       this.width = width;
       this.height = height;
        this.speedX = 0;
          this.speedY = 0;
           this.x = x;
         this.y = y;    
            this.update = function() {
          ctx = myGameArea.context;
          ctx.fillStyle = color;
           ctx.fillRect(this.x, this.y, this.width, this.height);
      }
       this.newPos = function() {
         this.x += this.speedX;
           this.y += this.speedY;        
      }    
   }
```

There's my snippet of code please help me with my collision between the wall and square. I also have buttons to move the square if you need to know.
Here's some more code for your convenience just please get me a answer thanks in advance.
I know its a lot of code but its also not all of it so ifyou need anything else just ask thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Adding addendum: This code will only check for square entity collisions, ie a tile based 2d style of game.  This will not work in a 3d based graphic set, or do any sort of fine collision detection (against non square entities).

Without seeing more of your code, such as how you're rendering or managing state of the entities, you just need a function call during your update() method, wherever that may be.

The method I used in a hobby project several years ago, the collision logic looked like this (a function that would return just a boolean).  This is just a jist I can give unless I see more of your code.

```
function isColliding(entity1, entity2) {
    var e1top = entity1.y;
    var e1bot = entity1.y + entity1.height;
    var e1left = entity1.x;
    var e1right = entity1.x + entity1.width;
    var e2top = entity2.y;
    var e2bot = entity2.y + entity2.height;
    var e2left = entity2.x;
    var e2right = entity2.x + entity2.width;
    var collision = true;
    if ((e1top > e2bot) || (e1bot < e2top) || (e1left > e2right) || (e1right < e2left))
        collision = false;
    return collision;
}
```